# Converting 1D array to 2D array regarding FOR loops Processing

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, processing

I am working on a tic-tac-toe game in my computer science class using processing. In my program, I am coding a 3 in a row checker and I am trying to code this using a 2D array code since my array was initialized as a 2D array when coding the X / O. As well as, my teacher gave us an example of doing this code but in a 1D array, and so I do not know how to convert his example regarding the FOR loops to 2D so that it can run onto my program. I have converted the array code to apply to my program, and it is running, but the code (FOR loops) regarding if someone won is not working. Can someone help me?

```
void onlyX() { //views only X pieces, runs checker for onlyX (attempted to 
convert to 2D array form)
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        if (boardPiece[i][j] == "X") {
          onlyXPiece[i][j] = "X";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /*void onlyX() { //1D Form 
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfBoardPieces; i++) {
      if (boardPiece[i] == "X") {
        onlyXPiece[i] = "X";
      }
    }
  }*/

void onlyO() { //views only O pieces, runs checker for onlyO (attempted to 
convert to 2D array form)
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
       if (boardPiece[i][j] == "O") {
         onlyOPiece[i][j] = "O";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /*void onlyO() { //1D form
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfBoardPieces; i++) {
      if (boardPiece[i] == "O") {
        onlyOPiece[i] = "O";
      }
    }
  }*/
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: @GBlodgett this is in Java-processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2D array FOR loop (usually called a double FOR LOOP) seems fine, though I can't quite understand why you would place the X's and O's in separate 2D arrays. There are multiple ways to check for a win condition, but this seems overly complex.

I adapted the double for loop at the top of your code to perform a win check that is easy to understand and usable for both X and O. Don't forget you also have to check for vertical and diagonal wins.

```
String[][] boardPiece = {{"X", "", "O"}, 
                         {"O", "O","O"}, 
                         {"X", "", "X"}};

void setup() {
  println("X wins = "+ str(checkRows("X")));
  println("O wins = "+ str(checkRows("O")));
}

boolean checkRows(String XorO) { 
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { //for every row
    boolean win = true;     //set win to true
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) { //for every column    
      if (boardPiece[i][j] != XorO) {  //if the column does not equal the sign that you are checking
        win = false;                   // meaning its the other, or it's empty, then set win to false
      }                                
    }
    if (win) {
      return true;    //if win is true, then there are 3 X's or 3 O's in this row, so return true
    }
  }
  return false;      // if none of the rows contain 3 equal, return false
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, means a lot. I was just wondering when you define boardpiece what are those three brackets and what do they mean?

Comment: It is an easy way to instantiate arrays: https://processing.org/reference/Array.html - String[] is an array of strings String[][] is a 2D array of strings. { a, b } fills the array with entries a and b.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so now that I know what boardpiece is, to make it work I need to make the brackets fill themselves in depending on the X and O that are placed correct?

Comment: Correct. Something like: if the mouseclick is in the area of the top middle tile, put X in boardpiece[0][1]

Comment: Thank you for your help regarding my issues, I have now a fully functional basic Tic-Tac-Toe game. I am now moving on to the AI part of the game, hopefully I will not face any troubles and I will try to tackle my problems on my own. If I do require help I will be posting it here hopefully, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Hey J.D.! The game is finished! If you have time, go and take a look at it, hope you enjoy! :)

Comment: It's nice, I really like the different AI's!

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm on to making this game on a website, using canvas. Hopefully I'll be able to learn it quickly. Glad you enjoyed the game :)

Comment: The game is finished in html too :P! Hope you enjoy :D J.D. ( same github, different folder)

Answer (score 2):

To check if someone has won the game you have to check the columns, rows and diagonals. Write a `checkBoard` function with one parameter, where you can specify the kind of piece (`"X"` pr `"O"`) which you want to check:

```java
boolean checkBoard(String p) {

    boolean won = false;

    // check rows and columns
    for (int i=0; !won && i<3; i++) {
        boolean eqRow = true;
        boolean eqCol = true;
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            eqRow = eqRow && boardPiece[i][j] == p;
            eqCol = eqCol && boardPiece[j][i] == p;
        }
        won = eqRow || eqCol;
    }

    // check diagonals
    if ( !won )
    {
        boolean d1 = true;
        boolean d2 = true;
        for (int i=0; !won && i<3; i++) {
            d1 = d1 && boardPiece[i][i] == p;
            d2 = d2 && boardPiece[2-i][i] == p;
        }
        won = d1 || d2;
    }

    return won;
}
```